# prevent creation new line in xslt transformation

Tags: xml, xslt, saxon

My sorce xml file

```
<numbers>
    <number>
        one
    </number>
    <number>
        two
    </number>
 <numbers>
```

and I have xsl file that translate into html. I want to construct text like this:

```
one, two
```

in output.

For this purpose I use

```
<xsl:value-of select="//numbers/number" separator=", "/>
```

but in output I'll see text with new line

```
one
, 
two
```

In browser it's look like 'one , two' (with spaces around comma sign). I want to get value without left space.

I use saxon he 9.4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `number` elements have white-space in them, including new-lines before and after the actual "one" text, and this is what is getting picked up.

As you are using XSLT2.0, change your expression to this to remove the white-space either side of the text

```
<xsl:value-of select="//numbers/number/normalize-space()" separator=", "/>
```